# Write / Read cookies from generic handler (.ashx) in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, generic-handler

I would like to know if there is a way to write and read cookies from a generic handler.

For now, when I check the cookies in the browser developer tools, they are null.

Here is my code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    CreateCookie(Username,SessionID);
}

public void CreateCookie(string userName, string sessionID)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["SESSION"]["SESSIONID"] = Encryption.EncryptString(sessionID);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["USER"]["USERNAME"] = Encryption.EncryptString(userName);

}
```

I cannot replace my cookies by SessionState element as the code can be executed on a server farm, messing up with the session.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get `Username` and `SessionID`?

Comment: I retrieve them from the queryString, but I haven't display this part of the code to focus on the cookies problem.

Comment: Have you debugged to see that 1) the values are making it all the way into `CreateCookie()` and 2) `Encryption.EncryptString()` is returning non-null values?

Comment: Yes, the value make it to the cookies assignment.
I've also tested this code out of the generic handler, and it create the cookies.. So it must comes from the generic handler.

Comment: Your code worked for me in an .ASHX handler.  How are you invoking the handler?

Comment: Hmmm interesting... I'm invoking the handler via an ajax call.
And this part seems to work too as I can see the values in debug mode :/

Answer (score 3):

Does the handler implement IReadOnlySessionState and IRequiresSessionState interfaces to access and manipulate session variables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

Comment: For now it only implement IRequiresSessionState. I'm gonna try with IReadOnlySessionState too.